How to play different audios on a single <audio> tag Django app
I'm making a music streaming website. On the homepage I have a carousel with songs and I want to play them onclick in a single HTML <audio> tag. How can I achieve that? Do I have to write a JavaScript function? If yes, how it should look like?
This is my HTML:
<div class="main-carousel" data-flickity='{"groupCells":5 , "contain": true, "pageDots": false, "draggable": false, "cellAlign": "left", "lazyLoad": true}'>
        {% for i in songs %}
            <div class="carousel-cell">
                <section class="main_song">
                    <div class="song-card">
                        <div class="containera">
                            <img src="{{i.image}}" id="A_{{i.id}}" alt="song cover">
                            <div class="overlaya"></div>
                            <div>
                                <a class="play-btn" href="...?" id="{{i.id}}"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-2x"></i></a>
                                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                    <div class="add-playlist-btn">
                                        <a id="W_{{i.song_id}}" title="Add to Playlist" onclick="showDiv(this)"></a>
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p class="songName" id="B_{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</p>
                        <p class="artistName">{{i.artist}}</p>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <audio preload="auto" controls id="audioPlayer">
        <source src=...?>
        </audio>

My models.py:
class Song(models.Model):
    song_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    album = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='Album')
    song = models.FileField(upload_to="songs/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp3', 'wav'])], default="name")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="songimage/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'])], default="https://placehold.co/300x300/png")
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']


You need to write a Javascript function.
Update your HTML to include the song URL in a data attribute for each play button:
<div class="main-carousel" data-flickity='{"groupCells":5 , "contain": true, "pageDots": false, "draggable": false, "cellAlign": "left", "lazyLoad": true}'>
    {% for i in songs %}
        <div class="carousel-cell">
            <section class="main_song">
                <div class="song-card">
                    <div class="containera">
                        <img src="{{i.image.url}}" id="A_{{i.id}}" alt="song cover">
                        <div class="overlaya"></div>
                        <div>
                            <a class="play-btn" href="#" data-song-url="{{i.song.url}}" id="{{i.id}}" onclick="playSong(this)"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-2x"></i></a>
                            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                <div class="add-playlist-btn">
                                    <a id="W_{{i.song_id}}" title="Add to Playlist" onclick="showDiv(this)"></a>
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="songName" id="B_{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</p>
                    <p class="artistName">{{i.artist}}</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<audio preload="auto" controls id="audioPlayer">
    <source src="" id="audioSource">
</audio>

Create the JavaScript function to play the song:
function playSong(element) {
    var songUrl = element.getAttribute('data-song-url');
    var audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
    var audioSource = document.getElementById('audioSource');
    audioSource.src = songUrl;
    audioPlayer.load();
    audioPlayer.play();
}

Ensure you include the JavaScript in your HTML file or in a linked JS file:
<script>
    function playSong(element) {
        var songUrl = element.getAttribute('data-song-url');
        var audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
        var audioSource = document.getElementById('audioSource');
        audioSource.src = songUrl;
        audioPlayer.load();
        audioPlayer.play();
    }
</script>


Solid, my first thought would have been to create a JS function inside of the loop that ties to each Django Obj after creation, this is clean with less code!

is not working i think for the {{i.song.url}}. The model Song has not a url attribute

can you show the error you get

no error. the button don't make anything and the song isn't played

Can you add a console.log(songUrl) and check the logs in inspector?

it says me "Unresolved variable or type i" if i make console.log(i.song.url) in the loop

maybe i have to define what is the url?

Actually it is “i” that is unresolved
You have to type console.log(songUrl) without the “i”

Add console.log(songUrl) below var songUrl = element.getAttribute('data-song-url'); and check

@charanvendra i got this 2 errors: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request  and  songnamefile.mp3:1  GET http: .../songnamefile.mp3 404 (Not Found)

it also display the song path like: /media/media/songs/songnamefile.mp3, but the path should be /media/songs/songnamefile.mp3. probably this is the problem

solved. I had to change the MEDIA_ROOT path and all works now, thanks!!

Great that it worked for you!
